# DateTime.strptime error

Tags: ruby

I need to convert Array data2 to DateTime.
String data works. Does anyone know why I get error with `Array.to_s` like below ?

```
require 'date'

data = "May  3 07:02:34"  
puts DateTime.strptime(data, '%b %d %H:%M:%S')<br>
puts data<br>
puts data.class

data2 = ["May  3 07:02:34"]

puts data2

puts data2.class

puts DateTime.strptime(data2.to_s, '%b %d %H:%M:%S')
```

**Output:**

```
2016-05-03T07:02:34+00:00
May  3 07:02:34
String  
May  3 07:02:34  
Array  
hello.rb:13:in `strptime': invalid date (ArgumentError)
    from hello.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're converting the array to a string, but really just want to reference the string at the first element.  Change your call to strptime to this:

```
puts DateTime.strptime(data2[0], '%b %d %H:%M:%S')
```

That should fix the issue with strptime.

Using Array#to_s renders the entire array as a string.  In this case, the result was this:

```
"[\"May 3 07:02:34\"]"
```

What you wanted (and got with index 0) is this:

```
"May 3 07:02:34"
```

The difference is important, and that's why strptime choked on it.  I hope that helps.

Comment: it works. Thanks. Still I wonder why data2.to_s errs. Any idea why ?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain why.  Let me know if you have any other questions, as well.